# Question about passport and DS-82 form

Tags: usa, passports

For anyone familiar with the passport process in the United States: I have a (valid, i.e. non-expired, etc.) passport card. However, as I will be traveling out of the continent I need a passport book. My first guess was to use the DS-11 form for a new passport book, but upon completing the state.gov's online application, it created a DS-82 form out of my information, and requested that I send my passport card along with a check and this form to the appropriate address.

My question is: is this a valid method of obtaining a passport book, even if I've never owned a passport book before? I thought if I never had a book I must fill out DS-11. But does my passport card count as a variant of this, so getting a book is like "renewing" in a way? I do not wish to renew my passport card since it did not expire.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought if I never had a book I must fill out DS-11.

But you had a passport. That is enough. Nowhere does the [official renew](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/renew.html) page make a distinction between book and card. It also says:

> You can renew your passport even if it has not expired.

And the first two steps to

> Submit a U.S. Passport Application by Mail (from within the United States):
>
> 1. Fill Out Form DS-82: Application For A U.S. Passport by Mail
> 2. Submit your **most recent** U.S. passport book and/**or card**

Emphasis mine. You do not need or want a [DS-11](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/forms.html) as that is for:

> Application for a U.S. Passport (for all first-time applicants, all minors, and applicants who are not eligible to use the DS-82)

So yes, you send in the DS-82 and the card and get a passport book. This is indeed a renewal.